# Eliminate all negative values in a list - R

Tags: r, list

my problem seemed to be easy, but somehow I don't come across a proper solution. I want to substitute all negative values in a list (!) in R by the value of 0.

For a vector or matrix this would be easy:

```
matrixx <- as.matrix(rnorm(20,0,0.5))
matrixx[matrixx<0] <- 0
```

But when I try to apply that to a list (with different lengths, all entries numeric), it returns:

> (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

I tried `unlist(x)`, but that doesn't seem to do the job either. What is it that I am missing?

Here is an exemplary data set:

```
 dummy_list <- list(0)
 dummy_list[[1]] <- c(-0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0)
 dummy_list[[2]] <- c(-5, -2, 10)
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 7):

Use `lapply` to apply an (anonymous) function to every element of your list.

Sample data :

```
> l <- list(x=rnorm(5), y=rnorm(3))
> l
$x
[1]  0.2682050  0.9015505 -0.8334734  1.3497408  1.9482120

$y
[1] -1.92907352 -0.24787634 -0.08115765
```

And then :

```
> lapply(l, function(v) {v[v<0] <- 0; v} )
$x
[1] 0.2682050 0.9015505 0.0000000 1.3497408 1.9482120

$y
[1] 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately that doesn't work for my data set. Maybe it's because my data is nested like this:

dummy_list <- list(0)
dummy_list[[1]] <- c(-0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0)

for several "upper levels" of different length. There is no error message, but negative values remain negative in my data set for your solution... (@juba: sorry, I had to edit this post, because I accidently hit "enter" too quickly ;))

Uff, hard to format, I will post another answer...

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataset in your question.

Comment: I have now. Any ideas? I tried several things, but it still doesn't work the way I want it to...